# Resources on UX/UI and Product Sound Design

Tags: sound-design, interface, theory, user-interface

Where can I find resources focused on the theory behind user interface and user experience sound design, especially for physical products such as phones, cars etc?

There are a few questions here on techniques for creating user interface sounds, but I'm more interested in the theory behind why certain sounds are more effective and appropriate in different situations. Examples of this could be why a certain sound on your phone is appropriate for a certain action, or how and why another sound might serve as a warning or alert you to a change a situation.

I'm expecting this to be a bit cross-disciplinary, so please post anything you think is relevant.

Comment: Might be a question for http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Fair point. I might post it there too, then see if anybody replies.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question Mark.
I would look at any research into psychoacoustics & psychophysics that you can find, ie, why we react in certain ways to certain sounds and how our brains are wired to do so (like when we hear a siren, usually a warning sign, or how we react to a babys cry etc).
Maybe these will help
http://www.tonmeister.ca/main/textbook/intro_to_sound_recordingch6.html#x24-3060005.3

http://www.zainea.com/physiologicalsound.htm

https://www.kent.ac.uk/arts/sound-journal/forrester001.html

Hope this helps